# Some characters in zsh don't show until the key is released

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, input

When inputting specific characters in zsh shell (in my case e and ;) they don't show up immediately after pressing the key. Instead they only show up a short time after releasing the key. When these keys are held down they do not show up while holding the key, but again only show up a short time after releasing. All other keys do show up immediately after pressing the key, and also show up  continuously while holding it down.
If I instead run bash in my terminal emulator, the problem is gone. 
I can't find anything on this, and thought I might be missing something obvious. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does `bindkey -e` cure these symptoms in the current zsh session?

Comment: bindkey -e does not cure it. A reboot cures it sometimes, but it does re-occur at (as far as I know) random times.

Comment: Hm, and it also occurs with no custom config loaded, i.e. using `zsh- f`?

Comment: No it does not happen with zsh -f, so it must be something in the config. And with a little testing I found what the problem was. The following lines were still in my zshrc:
`bindkey "eOc" emacs-forward-word`
`bindkey "eOd" emacs-backward-word`

Comment: The ; was fixed by removing the lines `bindkey ";5C" forward-word` and `bindkey ";5D" backward-word` but now I can sadly no longer jump words with control + arrow keys. Not too big a deal tho. Also, my terminal emulator is termite. Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Comment: While you worked out the first part yourself, I've wrote an answer for future visitors. I also included some hints, how to define `CTRL+LEFTARROW` correctly in the second part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a keybinding which consists of multiple characters, e.g.

```
bindkey 'foo' some_zle_widget
```

*zsh* has to wait until it is clear that you don't want to key in this key binding. In the above example the key stroke <kbd>f</kbd> will be delayed for some time. The delay will continue if you press <kbd>o</kbd>, but will be aborted if you press a key other than *o*.

So, to narrow down this issue start with a *clean* shell, i.e. without loading the usual config files by issuing `zsh -f`. The issue should vanish now (as you confirmed in the comments).

Next, check especially your `~/.zshrc` file, but also some system-wide configs in `/etc`, for offending *bindkey*  statements.

And finally, as you write in the comments that you want to bind to <kbd>CTRL + ←</kbd>, construct the correct line. To do that you need the code your terminal sends on pressing this key combination. You can use e.g. <kbd>CTRL + v</kbd><kbd>CTRL + ←</kbd>, because <kbd>CTRL + v</kbd> switches *zsh* to some kind of *literal mode* for the next key press.<sup>+</sup>

On *xterm* you get `^[[1;5D`, so the correct bindkey command will be

```
bindkey '^[[1;5D' backward-word
```

Please note that these key combinations are really different for different terminals!

---

<sup>+</sup>If it is not working, issue `bindkey -e` beforehand.